# How to use PreviousPage?

Tags: c#, .net, request, page-lifecycle

On `pippo.aspx` and `pippo2.aspx` pages (Webform, .NET 3.5) I have this code, in the Page_Load :

```
Response.Write("Result: " + Page.PreviousPage.Request["idconcorso"] + "");
```

Well, I call `pippo.aspx`, and the result is `Result:`.

Than, I call from `pippo.aspx` the page `pippo.aspx?idconcorso=1234` , and I aspect the result is again `Result:`, but in fact it print `Result: 1234`.

Than, I call from `pippo.aspx?idconcorso=1234` the page `pippo2.aspx`, and there I aspect `Result: 1234` , but in fact is `Result:`.

Where am I wrong?

P.S. when I say "call" I mean a simple `<a href>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your use of `Page.PreviousPage` isn't correct.

It is designed to be used with the Transfer method or cross-page posting.

> If the current page is being rendered as a result of a direct request  (not a transfer or >   cross-post from another page), the PreviousPage
>   property contains null.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.previouspage.aspx

So making a direct page request as you're doing won't give you the values from the previous page.

Comment: Uhm! So how can I do it with "direct request"? Is there a technology inside the .NET? Or I need to manage it with session/etc?

Comment: There are various ways you could do it. What is your use case specifically?

Comment: the one written on my example. In few words : I need to know the querystring of the page that has called the page where I am :)

Comment: That's not really a use case but anyway, you could do it a couple of ways. Either pass the previous value as a new querystring value to the new page (&previousPageId=1234) or store it in the session and retrive it on your current page.

Comment: I found this Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() : seems to works as well, also if (on server side) I do Response.Redirect or Server.Execute! Nice feature :)

Comment: Yeah, the UrlReferrer isn't always available but if it's working for you, good stuff.

Comment: uhm...what do you mean as `UrlReferrer isn't always available` ?

Comment: It probably won't cause any problems for within your app, but often when users come to your site from an external site, the UrlReferrer isn't always availab.e

Comment: ah, well, ok :) it is not what I'm looking for ;)